# How can I select a dynamic number of substrings at dynamically determined locations in a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql, substring

I have a string of information in my database that is a string of json, and I am trying to get a couple specific pieces of information from it. An example of the json is below, and I am trying to get the `SuID` and `Quantity` from each entry. There are times when there is only one entry and times when there are more than two, but they are always formatted like this though.

I've tried to use a combination of `charindex`, `left`, `right`, `substring`, and `replace`, but I can't figure out how to get it to work when there are multiple pieces I need.

```
[{
    "SuID": 8348,
    "SuParentSuID": 652,
    "Quantity": 0,
    "LeadTime": 72,
    "LeadTimeClosures": 0,
    "Transships": 0,
    "InventoryStatus": 2,
    "HasCurrentFeed": 1,
    "LeadTimeSource": 0,
    "GhcPrgBitwise": 0,
    "QuantityAdjustment": 0,
    "ExclusionCriteria": 0
}, {
    "SuID": 8349,
    "SuParentSuID": 652,
    "Quantity": 454,
    "LeadTime": 72,
    "LeadTimeClosures": 0,
    "Transships": 0,
    "InventoryStatus": 1,
    "HasCurrentFeed": 1,
    "LeadTimeSource": 1,
    "GhcPrgBitwise": 0,
    "QuantityAdjustment": 0,
    "ExclusionCriteria": 0
}]
```

And I need to get something like this table:

```
 Suid | Quantity
------|----------
 8348 |     0
 8349 |    454
```

Comment: Is this PostgreSQL or SQL-Server? Your tags don't make sense.

Comment: It's whatever is easiest for someone to find a solution. I can work with either on my end, but can't figure out how to do it to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Postgres** you can use an actual `json` datatype to make this *strikingly simple*:

```
SELECT j->>'Suid' AS suid
     , j->>'Quantity' AS quantity
FROM   json_array_elements(my_json) j
```

`my_json` being the JSON value of type `json`.
**Literal input** would be dead simple, too:

```
SELECT j->>'Suid' AS suid
     , j->>'Quantity' AS quantity
FROM   json_array_elements( '[{
       "SuID": 8348,
       "Quantity": 0,
       ...
   }, {
       "SuID": 8349,
       "Quantity": 454,
       ...
   }]'::json) j
```

[JSON Functions and operators in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need by splitting string to pieces between `{` and `}` and then splitting these pieces again.

Below is sample for SqlServer:

```
declare @str varchar(1000)
set @str = '[{ .... }]' -- string of JSON

select
    Suid = sb2.Value,
    Quantity = sb3.Value
from ftStringBetween(@str, '{', '}') sb
    outer apply ftStringBetween(sb.Value, '"SuID": ', ',') sb2
    outer apply ftStringBetween(sb.Value, '"Quantity": ', ',') sb3
```

Output is:

```
Suid    Quantity
------- ---------
8348    0
8349    454
```

Where `ftStringBetween` is string splitting function:

```
create function ftStringBetween
(
    @str varchar(1000),
    @tagStart varchar(50),
    @tagEnd varchar(50)
)
returns table as
return
    with [10](N) as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
        union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1),
    [1k](N) as (select 1 from [10] a cross join [10] b cross join [10] c),
    v3(N) as (select top (isnull(datalength(@str), 0)) row_number() over (order by @@spid) from [1k]),
    v4(N) as (select N + datalength(@tagStart) from v3 where charindex(@tagStart, @str, N) = N),
    v5(N1, N2) as (select N, N2=isnull(nullif(charindex(@tagEnd, @str, N), 0), datalength(@str) + 1) from v4)
    select Value = substring(@str, N1, N2-N1)
    from v5
```

I hope you can adjust it for your needs.